# Append cumulative list of lists python

Tags: python, list, extend

I am trying to extend a list of lists in a commulative way like this:

```
# Consider the following list of lists
l_Of_l = [ [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]
```

Desired result is:

```
l_extended = [ [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

So basically the size of the list remains the same after extending commulatively.

**Edit:**

Here is what I did initially:

```
l_Of_l = [ [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]
lista = []
for i in l_Of_l:
    lista.extend(i)
    print(list([i for i in lista]))
```

But then the result was:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this in the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this without itertools is to use Python's `sum` function to concatenate lists.

```
>>> L =  [ [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7] ]
>>> L_extend = [ sum(L[0:i+1], []) for i in range(len(L)) ]
```

Comment: Will take it as answer since you didn't use any library :-)
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks!  But in the future, do consider the power of the itertools functions as other answers here have shown, especially if you'll use it more than once in the same script.

Answer (score 6):

Use accumulate from itertools:

```
list(itertools.accumulate(l_Of_l))                                                                                              
Out: 
[[1],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a cumulative sum, just with lists. [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)  can do this.

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> lst = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]
>>> list(accumulate(lst))
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l_Of_l = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]
>>> [list(map(itemgetter(0), l_Of_l[:i+1])) for i in range(len(l_Of_l))]
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another method using list(range()) in list comprehension method.

```
lol =  [ [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7] ]
lol_test2 = [list(range(1, i+2))for i in range(len(lol))]
print(lol_test2)
```

Output:
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]

Comment: While the output of this code does indeed produce the desired output, what you are doing is merely reconstructing the list to be as desired NOT providing a generic solution to the problem. Change the list to [[2], [4], [6], [8]] and your solutions will not work. In all probability, the question has been simplified to a minimal code replication of a problem and any solution will then likely be applied to a very different list. Your answers must provide generic solution where possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for spotting and clarifying the error Galo. I greatly appreciate this and will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 lol =  [ [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7] ]
 lol_test = [[*range(1, i+2)]for i in range(len(lol))]
 print(lol_test)
```

I came up with a solution similar to Bill M, just a small difference. I am just a novice learning python.

And it worked with the same output: [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]